# Update chatbot to Bot Builder SDK v4

Tags: botframework, chatbot

Is there a manual describing migration from Bot Builder SDK v3 to v4?
I have a lot of compilation errors after updating NuGet packages

**Update**

It appeared to be difficult. In addition to the answer below, I found this post quite useful to get a general picture https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/martinkearn/2018/07/17/bot-framework-v4-what-i-learnt-in-4-days-in-july-2018/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just update your NuGet packages from V3 to V4, without changing your code. It is a major release with a lot of breaking changes.

The [roadmap](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/wiki/Roadmap) 
for botbuilder-dotnet describes that a migration path from V3 to V4 is still in progress. I would suggest to have a look at [BotBuilder-Samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples) and Microsoft Docs for the moment, to get an idea about how much has changed.

Answer (score 1):

There are lot of changes from V3 to V4, they have completely re-written the concepts, architecture and terminologies.
So just updating the libraries won't work, you must update the code as well.

The roll-out is still not complete so it is recommended to use v3 in production as of now.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade is almost equal to the efforts of writing the complete bot code again. In case you are comfortable with your existing bot functionality and is willing to add new features which has nothing to do with SDK version, you can do this using Bot Channel Registration. Steps to do this is mentioned in a blog here - https://chatbotslife.com/microsoft-bot-framework-sdk-3-code-on-azure-bot-service-without-migrating-to-sdk-4-14afa3300887